# $K\ge0$ such that for all $a>0$ and $b>0$ , $|\int_a^b \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt| \le K$

Tags: integration

Given that the integral converges for $a=0$ and $b=+\infty$, I thought about using a "uniformly bounded" argument on segments but it isn't sufficent since the segments are arbitrarily long.

Comment: Hint: consider that the 'humps' keep getting shallower and shallower.

Comment: And have alternating signs.

Comment: The optimal $K$, reached when $(a,b)=(0,\pi)$, is $\mathrm{Si}(\pi)\approx1.852$.

Answer (score 0):

The general case can be reduced to $a=1$ by writing the integral as the sum/difference of two. Then
$$\int_1^b \frac{\sin t }{t} = -\frac{\cos t}{t}\bigg|_1^b -\int_1^b \frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,dt$$
The first term on the right is bounded by $2$ in absolute value. The second is estimated as 
$$
\left|\int_1^b \frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,dt\right|\le \int_1^b \frac{1}{t^2}\,dt \le 1
$$